# Windows 10 の chkdsk に関するドキュメントはありますか？

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 10 の chkdsk について調べています。

[Windows Server の chkdsk に関するドキュメントは見つかった](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) のですが、これは Windows 10 にも適用されますか？

Windows Server と Windows 10 の違いが分からないのですが、同じNT系ですか？コアな部分はほぼ同一と考えてよいですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コマンドライン引数として `/?` を付けて実行すればオプション一覧が表示されるので、こちらを参照しているwebページのヘルプと見比べてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
# chkdsk /?
```